# How Link changeset with the documents on the sharepoint project portal for TFS 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, configuration

As I understand configuration management mean you have to track all your artifacts(requirement, design, code,test plan, test cases, test result, user manual) so at any point of time you can bring your changeset and see what the corresponding documents version with it, since we put our documents on the sharepoint not the source control and of curse we enable versioning, how can I link the changeset with the corresponding doc version and how also link the specific build with corresponding doc version

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason NOT to use TFS Source Control instead of SP?  Seems way easier.

Comment: You are right but I just want to go through the Microsoft way for managing the documents, thanks

Comment: There is a huge reason not to use TFS Source Control for storing documents.  They're not source.  This is precisely what Sharepoint sites along site a team project are designed for, to hold your related artifacts.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you are right but as DancesWithBamboo said it will be easier with TFS source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link your changesets to work items.
Link your work items to the version of the Sharepoint document you want using a hyperlink link type.

If you have versioning on your document libraries in sharepoint make sure you link to the specific version of the document, not just the most recent one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Richard's answer, you could edit the workflow to add custom fields in your work item linking to specific document types including the relevant version if you wanted.

If you encorce checkins must be associated with a valid work item, and that work item must have a link to a document, you have pretty good traceability.